# Windows smart locking? Prevent laptop from automatic locking when docked

Tags: windows, laptop, security, docking-station

I am using a Lenovo ThinkPad P53s (20N6) as my main personal computer, at home 99% of the time. Occasionally, I will bring it outside and it could be stolen. Therefore, I wish a potential thief who finds my laptop sleeping would have to enter my password/PIN. However, I frequently put the laptop to sleep (mostly to reduce energy waste), and find it annoying to have to enter a PIN/password every time. Since I live in a safe apartment and my security risk is moderate, I would be happy if "the lock screen was skipped" (unlocked automatically) whenever the laptop wakes at home.

Is there a **smart/convenient** (efficient) way to set Microsoft **Windows** 11 to automatically unlock / **stay unlocked when it's at its usual location** (my desk at home)? Given my **moderate security** requirements, I would be satisfied if "at home" was considered equivalent to ***on its docking station***, but I can imagine a number of additional/alternative criteria to verify that, including being attached to my monitor, my mouse, my keyboard (and potentially connected to my wireless network).

Precisions:

- The docking station is a Lenovo ThinkPad 135 W Ultra (40AJ0135US).
- This laptop has no fingerprint reader.
- The only camera I have is generally unavailable (since the laptop's lid is closed when it's docked).
- I do not consider having to develop software for that as "convenient", although I do not exclude installing a component for that, even if it's not published by Microsoft.
- Although I am confident that my docking station transmits a unique identifier (some sort of serial number), I would consider a solution satisfying even if it merely checked that it is docked on a station of the same model as mine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your laptop is on battery when you bring it outside,
and is plugged-in when inside,

The following command will disable the requirement for the password
when the laptop is plugged-in:

```
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 0
```

Comment: Your assumption would be mostly valid, except by "outside", I mean outside my home (whether that is indoors or outdoors). Basically, I am asking how to prevent a thief from using my laptop if it's stolen while I brought it out of my home. I want to prevent a potential thief from reading the data on my laptop (unless he has access to computer science talent).

Comment: If you encrypt your data, even computer science talent will not help access the data. I would advise against full-disk encryption as too fragile.

Comment: That depends on encryption, but thanks anyway, I have no intention to encrypt at this time so let's not get into that. All I want to know is whether Windows or an add-on allow me to *lock* *smartly*.